# How to replace "\" with "/" in java?

Tags: java, string, escaping

I have a string like s = "abc\def" and I want to replace "" with "/" and makes the string like "abc/def/".

I tried `replaceAll("\\","/")` but the compiler is giving error for string

> error: illegal escape character
> String s="abc\def";

Comment: If you're defining a string literal you need to escape the backslash there as well: `String s = "abc\\def"`. Then, since `replaceAll()` takes a regex, you need to escape the backslash in the regex too and since the regex would be added as a literal you'd need double escaping: `replaceAll("\\\\", "/")` (`"\\\\"` to get the regex ``\\``).

Comment: but the thing is I can't change the string. The data is fetched from an excel sheet and I need the string in "abc/def/" format but currently it's in "abc\def\" format.

Comment: @MUSKANRANI If the string was fetched from an Excel sheet, you wouldn’t be getting the error message that you posted. That error message *specifically* refers to a literal string in your Java code.

Comment: Yes Konrad I am getting this error because after fetching the data from excel I am storing it in String and then doing the process.

String s = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();    // Like this

Comment: `String s = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();` cannot result in `illegal escape character String s="abc\def";`. That message specifically refers to literals and it already states the literal you've used, i.e. `"abc\def"`. Thus that error probably only occurs in your test code while your actual code probably results in a `PatternSyntaxException` due to the missing regex-escape of the backslash.

Comment: Yes correct, Actually previously I was using replaceAll() and now I tried with replace, it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Java uses `\` as the string escape character, but also as the regex escape character, and `replaceAll` performs a regex search. So you need to *doubly escape* the backslash (once to make it a literal `\` in the string, and once to make it a literal character in the regular expression):

```
result = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Alternatively, you don’t actually need regular expressions here, so the following works as well:

```
result = str.replace("\\", "/");
```

Or, indeed, using the single-char replacement version:

```
result = str.replace('\\', '/');
```

Comment: You are correct, but the error is on the string `"abc\def"` because `\d` is not a valid escape sequence.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam You’re right, I had missed that. However, OP has now clarified that the error message is actually unrelated to the *actual* issue.